# How to deal with multiple (same) occurences returned from a For loop?

Tags: python, loops, find-occurrences

So, i’m trying to find a solution for my program (adressbook), when a For loop returns multiple occurences for e.g. lastname. (Lastname == ‘brown’).

I’ve created this for loop which will return all records found with (lastname ‘brown’). Next i would like to let the user decide which record he/she wants to change the adress for.

As you can see there are multiple occurences for brown.

Result Loop:

```
OrderedDict([('lastname', 'brown'), ('name', 'emma'), ('street', 'hillstreets'), ('number', '6558'), ('city', 'houston')])
OrderedDict([('lastname', 'brown'), ('name', 'eric'), ('street', 'bluestreet'), ('number', '23'), ('city', 'capetown')])
```

I can print both names, but next i want to let the user decide which 'brown' he/she wants to change the adress for?
So e.g. print a message like: 'multiple records found for lastname 'brown'. For which 'brown' u want to change the adress for?

```
import sys
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

filename = "adresses.csv"
adressbook = []

with open(filename) as f:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in csv_reader:
        adressbook.append(row)

    row_count = sum(1 for row in adressbook)
    n = row_count
    for row in adressbook[0:n]:
        value = 'brown'
        if row['lastname'] == value:
            print(row)
```

Comment: You need to decide exactly how you want it to behave.  Should it list all of them, numbered, and then ask for the number of the one to use?  Should it request the first name, or the street name?  Design it, then try to implement it.

Comment: The design would be to number the ones to use and let the user decide for which number he/she wants to change the adress.

Comment: Off topic hint:`row_count = sum(1 for row in adressbook); n = row_count` is equivalent to `n = len(adressbook)` - (_and address book is written with two d in address in english btw..._)

Comment: whatever solution you finally want to implement - you should at first save the indices of the found addresses in another list (besides only printing them for debugging purpose), so that you can access it: 1. for presenting it to the user and 2. for reacting correctly to their choice.